Can the inclusion $C_b(X) \hookrightarrow C(X)$ admit a retraction?
Does there exist an example of a non-pseudocompact Tychonoff space $X$ such that the inclusion $\iota: C_b(X) \hookrightarrow C(X)$ has a retraction, meaning a ring homomorphism $\pi: C(X) \twoheadrightarrow C_b(X)$ with $\pi \circ \iota = \operatorname{id}_{C_b(X)}$?

Note that for pseudocompact spaces, we have $C(X) = C_b(X)$, so this case is not interesting. Also, the restriction to Tychonoff spaces is not actually a restriction, since for any topological space $X$ we have a Tychonoff space $Y$ and a surjection $X \to Y$ inducing an isomorphism $C(X) \cong C(Y)$.


The answer is no. Let $X$ be a non-pseudocompact Tychonoff space. Striving for a contradiction, assume that there is a ring homomorphism $\pi: C(X) \twoheadrightarrow C_b(X)$ with $\pi \circ \iota = \operatorname{id}_{C_b(X)}$. Take any $f \in C(X) \setminus C_b(X)$. Set
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & |f(x)| \leq 1 \\ \frac{1}{|f(x)|} & |f(x)| \geq 1 \\ \end{cases}
$$
Clearly, we have $g \in C_b(X)$. We also have
$$
(f \cdot g)(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & |f(x)| \leq 1 \\ \frac{f(x)}{|f(x)|} & |f(x)| \geq 1 \\ \end{cases}
$$
Hence we see that $f \cdot g \in C_b(X)$. So now we have
$$
\pi(\iota(g) \cdot f) = \pi(\iota(g)) \cdot \pi(f) = g \cdot \pi(f)
$$
But also
$$
\pi(\iota(g \cdot f)) = g \cdot f
$$
However, since $g$ is invertible in $C(X)$, this implies that $\pi(f) = f$, a contradiction to $\pi(f) \in C_b(X)$.

Did you just post to show us your solution?

@MartinBrandenburg It's a question that I found rather natural. As far as I understand, asking and answering your own questions is encouraged on this site. Or did I understand this incorrectly? In that case, I can also delete the post.

@MartinBrandenburg https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

@MartinBrandenburg The above link is what shows up when you click the "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style" checkbox
